# L9110 motor driver burning after some random time

Tags: motordriver, overheat

I did a quick prototype of a plotter (two motors for x and y axes, one servo for the pen up/down).

I'm using a [L9110 module](https://www.electrodragon.com/w/File:L9110S_Schematic.jpg) (dual H bridge board) to control the x and y motors. The power supply for the motors is a 2S Lipo battery.

Everything is working as expected, except that once in a while (let's say, on average, twice per hour), one of the two H-bridges of the L9110 module starts to smoke (and no longer works afterwards). I destroyed four of these modules without managing to find out why.

I already excluded the most obvious reasons:

- inverted polarity: not possible because the circuit was running fine when it happened (I didn't plug/unplug any wire at that moment)
- over-current: seems quite unlikely: the motors draw a maximum of 300 mA each (when output of reductor is blocked), which is well below the 800 mA per motor allowed in continuous operation. And when I touch the drivers, they are not hot. In addition, it's not always the same one of the two H-bridges that burns.

Do you have any idea?
Maybe a bad contact on the connection between the Arduino ground and the LiPo/driver ground (but why would this  burn the driver)?

**Additional information:**
*the motor driver is an "L9110" module I bought [here](https://www.robot-maker.com/shop/drivers-d-actionneurs/56-driver-pour-moteurs-cc-l9110-56.html) (nb: page in French). There is a "datasheet" in English for the module [here](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1133008/ETC2/L9110S.html) and a poor datasheet for the H-bridge itself [here](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/4489/4489_datasheet-l9110.pdf). Note that on the H-bridge it says L9110S and not L9110, but I couldn't find out whether this S has any meaning, or if it is just the SOP8 package (vs DIP8).

For the circuit in more detail:

- an Arduino Uno Clone is connected to the USB port of the laptop
- the servo is powered directly from the Arduino (GND, +5 V, PWM pin 11), as it is a small 9g servo ([SG90](https://protosupplies.com/product/servo-motor-micro-sg90/)) that doesn't need much current
- the 4 signal pins of the driver are connected to PWM pins 3, 5, 6 and 9 of the Arduino
- the ground of the driver is connected on a breadboard with the ground of the Arduino and the ground of the 2S Lipo
- the Vcc pin of the driver is directly connected to the + of the 2S Lipo
- the motors are connected on the motor outputs of the driver

EDIT: as asked, I add the schematics of my circuit: [image: schematics of circuit]

Comment: Try lowering the voltage supply of the driver. Or try first with a power supply with max current adjustable and ammeter included. Try to glue a radiator on each component.

Comment: With such poor documentation, I'm wondering what would be the motivation to choose this device at all. Nothing in what I quickly read gave any indication that shoot-through control was implemented.

Comment: Lowering the voltage won't do (I can't afford to loose any torque), but I'm well within the limits (2S = 2*4.2=8.4V max, the circuit is given for up to 12V).
And I have no supply with current limit at hand.

Comment: @Andyaka I bought those from the french link I provided during the first lock down (the seller is a serious guy, and he was able to ship quickly when most other french online shops had closed). I ended up not using them for the project I brough them for, so I have still 8 of them in stock (now 4 remain).

For shot through, do you think it possible that the manufacturer didn't include this basic feature on an IC with only 2 inputs per motor (so no way for the user to insert dead time)?

Comment: What is your sequence of driving ? see the last picture of this.  https://www.elecrow.com/download/datasheet-l9110.pdf Only one input at level High, first two lines of "logical relationship" and adaptative PWM.

Comment: I'm putting 0V on one pin, and a PWM on the other one (nb : for now, I'm using only 100% duty cycle, in order to run full speed). I always have a delay of at least 500ms before changing direction

Comment: As stated in the last picture, applying only a signal for one direction on IA pin, low for IB, and vice-versa, the signal on IB pin, 0 for IA? NB : 100% immediately, and not progressively? Remember that it can be a peak current that L9110 would not like.

Comment: I hadn't thought of current peaks : i'm indeed going directly to 100%. I would expect that 1.5A peak current shouldn't be reached, but it's worth checking.
And anyway, an acceleration ramp can't harm.
What surprises me if it is current peaks, is that it occurs that late : I'm working mainly with very short displacements, so I do hundreds of starts/stops before failure

Comment: @Antonio51 : I measured the peak current for one of the motors (directly connecting/disconnecting the battery to the motor (through a 0.5 ohms power resistor to measure current with the scope). I had peaks of about 2V (decaying in 0.1-0.2 seconds). It should be enough to explain the problem.
If you put your suggestion as answer, I can accept it as such

Comment: @Sandro I added the specifications also for SG90. Current requirements is ... 100-250 mA ! Stalled 360 mA. <<<The servo runs on 5V with a current draw about 10mA at idle and 100mA to 250mA when being commanded to move depending on how it is being operated.   One SG90 can typically be driven off the power pin of an Arduino when experimenting, but motors in general are electrically noisy and power hungry devices.  It is always better to drive them directly off of a power supply rather than trying to power from the on-board Arduino regulator whenever possible>>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this ... https://www.elecrow.com/download/datasheet-l9110.pdf

Use this table, only the first three lines.

When using one input as high (PWM), change duty from 0 to 100% slowly (depending from motor specifications). So, current motor will not exceed specification "current limit" of L9110.

[image]

As stated in this picture, applying only a signal for one direction on IA pin, low for IB, and vice-versa, the signal on IB pin, 0 for IA.

[image]

NB : **not 100% immediately ON, but progressively**.

Remember that it can be a **big "peak current"** that L9110 would not like **when motors are switched ON**.

Example of servo-motor without armature current limiting.

One can see the peak current vs the steady state current ... between the two pulses.

[image]